# Randomly generate an element from an array VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am trying to create a program to randomly generate a name from a cake rota array. I cannot seem to get it to work. Currently, the message box shows a random number rather than the name stored in the array. Help please!

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim strNames(18) As String
        Dim frances, emma, piotr, jake, jess, jonah, john, flynn, will, nick As String

        strNames(0) = "frances"
        strNames(1) = "emma"
        strNames(2) = "piotr"
        strNames(3) = "jake"
        strNames(4) = "jess"
        strNames(5) = "jonah"
        strNames(6) = "john"
        strNames(7) = "flynn"
        strNames(8) = "will"
        strNames(9) = "nick"


        Dim rnum As Integer
        Dim temp As String
        For i = 0 To 18
            strNames(i) = i
        Next i

        Randomize()
        For i = 0 To 9
            rnum = Int(Rnd() * (UBound(strNames) - LBound(strNames) + 1) + LBound(strNames))
            temp = strNames(i)
            strNames(i) = strNames(rnum)
            strNames(rnum) = temp
        Next i


        For i = 0 To 9
            MessageBox.Show(strNames(i))
        Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: You don't appear to be picking a random name from an array, you appear to be shuffling the array, in a weird and probably wrong way (the key difference is that `rnum` has to depend on `i`). Please see [how to shuffle array in VB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23576469/11683) or [Shuffling an array of strings in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29358857/11683).

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
    For i = 0 To 18
        strNames(i) = i
    Next i
```

is setting the values of strNames to a number.

Taken out and it appears to work

```
    Dim strNames(18) As String
    Dim frances, emma, piotr, jake, jess, jonah, john, flynn, will, nick As String
    frances = "frances"
    emma = "emma"
    piotr = "piotr"
    jake = "jake"
    jess = "jess"
    jonah = "jonah"
    john = "john"
    flynn = "flynn"
    will = "will"
    nick = "nick"
    strNames(0) = frances
    strNames(1) = emma
    strNames(2) = piotr
    strNames(3) = jake
    strNames(4) = jess
    strNames(5) = jonah
    strNames(6) = john
    strNames(7) = flynn
    strNames(8) = will
    strNames(9) = nick


    Dim rnum As Integer
    Dim temp As String


    Randomize()
    For i = 0 To 9
        rnum = Int(Rnd() * (UBound(strNames) - LBound(strNames) + 1) + LBound(strNames))
        temp = strNames(i)
        strNames(i) = strNames(rnum)
        strNames(rnum) = temp
    Next i


    For i = 0 To 9
        MessageBox.Show(strNames(i))
    Next i
```

Comment: Thank you very much